# How to calculate the equilibrium (initial probability) for second order HMM in python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, matrix, hidden-markov-model, numpy

I have a transition matrix looks like:

```
p_transition = np.array([[0.5, 0.5],
                         [0.3, 0.7],
                         [0.4, 0.6],
                         [0.2, 0.8]])
```

Where each row represents the combination of states and column represents next state. For example, let A and B be two possible states, the entry for second row and first column is when getting sequence 'AB' the probability of next state being 'A' is 0.3.

I define the initial probability as the probability of getting all possible state sequences with shape (row of transition matrix, 0). I calculated the initial probability by following.

```
def equilibrium_p_init(p_trainsition):

  n_states = p_transition.shape[0]

  A = np.append(arr = p_transition.T - np.eye(n_states),
                values = np.ones(n_states).reshape(1, -1),
                axis = 0)
  
  pinv = np.linalg.pinv(A)

  return pinv.T[-1]

equilibrium_p_init(p_transition)
```

I got error:

```
<ipython-input-96-0c397629c2d4> in equilibrium_p_init(p_trainsition)
      3   n_states = p_transition.shape[0]
      4 
----> 5   A = np.append(arr = p_transition.T - np.eye(n_states),
      6                 values = np.ones(n_states).reshape(1, -1),
      7                 axis = 0)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4) (4,4)
```

How should I calculate the initial probability for the second order?
Alternatively, for higher orders, how should I calculate the initial probabilities?

Comment: Can you also explain *how* you intend to calculate the initial probability theoretically?

Comment: I found this code online lol. My initial intend was to do matrix multiplication until I reach the equilibrium, but the size won't match.

Comment: Can you share the source as well? Your subtraction has matrices of different dimensions.

Comment: https://ericmjl.github.io/essays-on-data-science/machine-learning/markov-models/       The source is about inferring the equilibrium for first order HMM